# Bad Request with valid geojson feature for 10 meter DEM

Tags: descartes-labs-platform

I'm using a valid geojson to do a simple search for a DEM and then trying to access the numpy array from the search (following the descartes labs tutorial raster_data_access). The search apparently succeeds but when I try to access the height band contained in the result, I get a weird error that I'm not sure how to debug. I'm wondering if the search result is empty because of a projection issue or something else.

Here is the code that fails:

```
# import packages
import descarteslabs as dl
from descarteslabs.workflows import *
import numpy as np
import geojson
from ipyleaflet import Map, GeoJSON # to show that the geojson is valid, we plot it

with open("dangermond.geojson") as f:
    fc = geojson.load(f)

fcd = load_geojson(fc)

m = Map(center=(34.50, -120.38), zoom=11)
m.add_layer(GeoJSON(data=fc))
m


scenes, ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    aoi=fc['features'][0],
    products='3dep:10meter_dem'
)

%matplotlib inline
a = scenes[0].ndarray(
    bands='hillshade',
    ctx=ctx
)

dl.scenes.display(a)
```

results in this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6bd7e336c5cf> in <module>
     24 a = scenes[0].ndarray(
     25     bands='hillshade',
---> 26     ctx=ctx
     27 )
     28 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/descarteslabs/scenes/scene.py in ndarray(self, bands, ctx, mask_nodata, mask_alpha, bands_axis, raster_info, resampler, processing_level, scaling, data_type, raster_client)
    536             )
    537             msg = msg.format(err=e, args=json.dumps(full_raster_args, indent=2))
--> 538             six.raise_from(BadRequestError(msg), None)
    539 
    540         if len(arr.shape) == 2:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

BadRequestError: Error with request:
{"message":"Output width or height is less than 1 pixel: width=0.5145911999999981 height=0.5133674999999996","status_code":400}

For reference, dl.Raster.ndarray was called with these arguments:
{
  "inputs": "3dep:10meter_dem:floatn35w121_13",
  "order": "gdal",
  "bands": [
    "hillshade",
    "alpha"
  ],
  "scales": null,
  "data_type": "Byte",
  "resampler": "near",
  "processing_level": null,
  "cutline": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -120.502853,
          34.513064
        ],
        [
          -120.503883,
          34.512356
        ],
        [
          -120.497875,
          34.494673
        ],
        [
          -120.494442,
          34.493824
        ],
        [
          -120.493584,
          34.492127
        ],
        [
          -120.490322,
          34.487174
        ],
        [
          -120.479851,
          34.478967
        ],
        [
          -120.473671,
          34.453351
        ],
        [
          -120.473156,
          34.448113
        ],
        [
          -120.471096,
          34.447547
        ],
        [
          -120.465603,
          34.448538
        ],
        [
          -120.464058,
          34.446556
        ],
        [
          -120.457706,
          34.442876
        ],
        [
          -120.451698,
          34.442168
        ],
        [
          -120.451012,
          34.446273
        ],
        [
          -120.445518,
          34.447547
        ],
        [
          -120.44363,
          34.450378
        ],
        [
          -120.435047,
          34.450095
        ],
        [
          -120.426121,
          34.449246
        ],
        [
          -120.420284,
          34.448821
        ],
        [
          -120.418568,
          34.452643
        ],
        [
          -120.415478,
          34.453776
        ],
        [
          -120.412216,
          34.492834
        ],
        [
          -120.376167,
          34.494532
        ],
        [
          -120.367584,
          34.499908
        ],
        [
          -120.361576,
          34.499625
        ],
        [
          -120.357971,
          34.500474
        ],
        [
          -120.357971,
          34.503869
        ],
        [
          -120.361233,
          34.504718
        ],
        [
          -120.364838,
          34.51561
        ],
        [
          -120.372562,
          34.516883
        ],
        [
          -120.374794,
          34.523106
        ],
        [
          -120.410328,
          34.53753
        ],
        [
          -120.405006,
          34.543045
        ],
        [
          -120.407238,
          34.547428
        ],
        [
          -120.421486,
          34.54757
        ],
        [
          -120.424747,
          34.546439
        ],
        [
          -120.431614,
          34.549408
        ],
        [
          -120.430069,
          34.55987
        ],
        [
          -120.488434,
          34.575843
        ],
        [
          -120.492554,
          34.512215
        ],
        [
          -120.502853,
          34.513064
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "resolution": 10.0,
  "srs": "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs ",
  "bounds_srs": "EPSG:4326",
  "align_pixels": true,
  "bounds": [
    -120.503883,
    34.442168,
    -120.357971,
    34.575843
  ],
  "dimensions": null
}
​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs due to a mismatch in units between the catalog product initial projection (degrees) and the units of the product band (meters). This is a platform bug, which should be addressed by making sure that product images and band units are in alignment. Here we are using the product `3dep:10meter_dem`.

To quickly fix the issue, you can re-assign the resolution of the `ctx` such that it's equal to 10m at the equator in degrees, as shown below. Be aware, however, that ideally the resolution in degrees would be defined at the location of interest, rather than at the equator.

```
scenes, ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    aoi=fc['features'][0],
    products='3dep:10meter_dem'
)

# reassign the resolution in degrees
ctx = ctx.assign(resolution=0.0000833333)
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to define the `ctx` with a resolution in meters corresponding to the region of interest, you can create an AOI using the local epsg code and the resolution in meters. Get the epsg code and edit the geocontext using the following code:

```
def wgs_to_epsg(lat, lon):
    """
    Get the epsg code from a (lat, lon) location
    """
    import math
    
    utm_band = str((math.floor((lon + 180) / 6) % 60) + 1)
    if len(utm_band) == 1:
        utm_band = "0" + utm_band
    if lat >= 0:
        epsg_code = "326" + utm_band
    else:
        epsg_code = "327" + utm_band
    return epsg_code

scenes, ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    aoi=fc['features'][0],
    products='3dep:10meter_dem'
)

# Get the epsg code corresponding to the location of the geojson. 
# This works here because the current `ctx.bounds` are defined in latitude
# and longitude coordinates
assert ctx.bounds_crs in ["EPSG:4326"], "ctx.bounds_crs must be EPSG:4326 for the example to work"

lon, lat = ctx.bounds[:2]
epsg_code = wgs_to_epsg(lat, lon)

# Create a new AOI with the appropriate resolution and crs
ctx = dl.scenes.AOI(
    ctx.geometry,
    resolution=10.0,
    crs=f"EPSG:{epsg_code}",
)
```

When the product projection and band units are in alignment, this issue will not happen. For example, the original code example with the Sentinel-2 product `sentinel-2:L1C`, does not yield an error.